# Using REPLACE INTO with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the REPLACE query to replace the contents of one table with the other table.
Here's my table:

**table_one**

- id
- name

**table_two**

- id
- fname
- lname

Here's the query that I'm currently using:

```
REPLACE INTO tbl_two (id, fname)
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_one
```

How do I do it so that the existing values in the `lname` field doesn't become `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, REPLACE INTO will delete and recreate a row when an existing row (identified by PK or UNIQUE) is found

you may rather use

```
INSERT INTO...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

INSERT INTO tbl_two (id, fname)
SELECT t.id, t.name FROM tbl_one t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = t.id, fname = t.name
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/320de/1)

Answer (score 2):

Loosely speaking, the documented behavior of REPLACE is to insert (if the primary key doesn't exist in the target), or to delete and insert.

If the primary key exists in the target, that row will be deleted, and the REPLACE statement will act like a SQL INSERT statement. So all the values in the new row have to be supplied either a) by the REPLACE statement, or b) by default values in the table definition.

If you want some of the old values to persist, you have to select them from the target table, and supply those values as part of the REPLACE statement.

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` might be a better choice.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

REPLACE INTO table_two (id, fname, Lname)
SELECT id, fname,"" FROM table_one

Try it out at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67a0f/1  using the following scripts

CREATE TABLE table_one(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   fname VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE table_two(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   fname VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   Lname VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_two (id, fname)
SELECT id, ISNULL(name,'') FROM tbl_one
```

try above sql query. ISNULL function convert null value in ''(blank).

Comment: replace into != insert into. The OP want's to update existing values and insert non existing one.